# HttpServletRequest#getParts() jsp always return empty collection

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat7

I have to develop a jsp to perform file uploads. I'm using Tomcat7 and servlet-api 3.0. If I start Tomcat from servers in Eclipse the jsp works well,  otherwise if I deploy the war in tomcat the jsp doesn't work. The problem is that request.getParts() reutrn always an empty collection.
What am I doing wrong?

This is my jsp:

```
    <%@page import="javax.servlet.http.Part" %>
    <%@page import="java.util.Collection"%>

    <html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>Test File Upload</h1>
      <br/>

        <form action="test.jsp" name="fileForm" id="fileForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <input type="text" name="text-test" value="" />
            <input type="file" name="upload" />
            <input type="submit" id="commit" name="commit" value="Upload">
        </form>
<%
    try {
        Part part = request.getPart("upload");
        System.out.println(part == null ? "part upload is null" : "part upload size : " + part.getSize());
        Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
        System.out.println("parts size: " + parts.size());
        for (Part p: request.getParts()) {
            out.write("Part name: " + p.getName() + "<br/>\n");
            out.write("<br/>\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the console output:

```
part upload is null
parts size: 0
```

Comment: Also doesn't work when I use a Tomcat server inside Eclipse.

Comment: I mean it does work neither in a standalone Tomcat nor in Tomcat server inside Eclipse. Maybe you are using Jetty when you run from Eclipse?

Comment: I'm using tomcat7. I'm sure because I have only tomcat configured in eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multipart functionality must be enabled explicitly for a servlet, either using a multipartconfig in `web.xml` or a `@MultipartConfig` annotation.

If not enabled `request.getParts()` will never return a non-empty set. (Note that I couldn't reproduce your findings for a Tomcat started from Eclipse).

Doing this configuration for a JSP page is tricky (don't know if `@MultipartConfig` can be applied to JSP pages), but here is a solution using `web.xml`: Given that your JSP page is `/test.jsp` you need to add:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-name>testjsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/test.jsp</jsp-file>
    <multipart-config>
        <!-- enter your values -->
        <max-file-size>123456</max-file-size> 
        <max-request-size>123456</max-request-size>
        <file-size-threshold>123456</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testjsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In your JSP page you also must check if the request is a multipart-request, else `getParts()` throws an error:

```
<%
String contentType = request.getContentType();
if ((contentType != null) && contentType.startsWith("multipart/form-data"))
{
    Part part = request.getPart("upload");
   ...
```

Comment: What if I have to write code in a framework where I just get the request object?

Comment: @basZero once you've got a request, the servlet initialization (including its multipart setting) is finished and you can't change it. Maybe your framework has some proprietary ways to enable multiparts during an initialization phase?